# How to comprehend the stack trace to get to the reason for the crash from android crash report

Tags: android, expandablelistview, crash-reports

Below is the crash report I received from my app published for alpha testing. Can anyone throw some light on how I should read this? It says `NullPointerException`, but where?  I have an expandable list view, is it because it is getting a null object to bind to a list item?
This is the method that seems to be throwing the NPE:

```
@Override
public View getChildView(int parent, int child, boolean arg2,
        View convertView, ViewGroup container) {
    ViewHolder mHolder;
    CategoryEntity childEntity = childlist.get(parent).get(child);
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.category_row, container,
                false);
        mHolder = new ViewHolder();
        mHolder.cateogoryname = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.textView);
        mHolder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        convertView.setTag(mHolder);
    } else {
        mHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    if (childEntity != null) {
        String replace = childEntity.getSq_displayName().equals("") ? childEntity
                .getCatname() : childEntity.getSq_displayName().replace(
                "<br>", "");

        Spannable span = new SpannableString(replace);
        switch (childEntity.getSq_cat_id()) {
        case 1:
            mHolder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_food);
            break;
        case 2:
            mHolder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_home);
            break;
        case 3:
            mHolder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_apparels);

            mHolder.cateogoryname.setText(replace);
            break;
        case 4:
            mHolder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_beauty);

            break;
        case 5:
            mHolder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_electronics);
            break;
        case 6:
            mHolder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_mobile);

            break;

        }
        span.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.rgb(0, 161, 220)), 0, 1,
                Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        span.setSpan(new android.text.style.StyleSpan(
                android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD), 0, 1,
                Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        span.setSpan(new AbsoluteSizeSpan(18, true), 0, 1,
                Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        mHolder.cateogoryname.setGravity(GravityCompat.START);

        mHolder.cateogoryname.setText(span);
    }

    return convertView;
}
```

This is the stack trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.application.app.entity.e.getChildView(Unknown Source)
at android.widget.ExpandableListConnector.getView(ExpandableListConnector.java:451)
at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2271)
at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1269)
at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1181)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15323)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4924)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1421)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:698)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:579)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15323)
at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(Unknown Source)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15323)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4924)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:315)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15323)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4924)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1421)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most relevant line here is `com.application.app.entity.e.getChildView`.

It's saying there is a `java.lang.NullPointerException` at this line. Maybe you are trying to access a view that is not yet initialized (i.e. it's null).

Comment: But i dont have any class with that name, i have package com.application.app.entity. When i ctrl+h it on eclipse the only place i could find this text was on dump.txt and i have no idea what that is.

Comment: This problem is only with the apk downloaded from playstore. the same signed apk installed using adb runs fine.

Comment: I can help you out better if you post the relevant code section here: com.application.app.entity.e

Comment: I updated the question. that's the getChildView method from the ExpandableListAdpater child class. I reckon that's the method which's throwing an exception, correct me if i'm wrong

Comment: Works perfectly fine when i debug or run the unsigned apk directly on the device.

Comment: are you using proguard for the release apk?

Comment: try compiling without it. Proguard sometimes causes obscure bugs like this. Unless your app requires very high levels of security, Proguard is not really necessary.

Comment: Had the same problem on a few user´s devices. costed me bad ratings and I had no clue what caused this problem. now I exclude the adapter from proguard and hope everything works again